# jquery javascript content filtering

Tags: javascript, jquery, filter, plugins

I'm looking for a pre-made content/text filter plugin that checks (as the user types in a textbox) the typed words against a list of inappropriate words.  I then want to provide some sort of alert box or flag notifying the user that this language is unacceptable...

Again, I'm looking for the easy-way-out, an existing content filter plugin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I developed my own content filter using AJAX and a blacklist of over 450 bad words.  When the submit button is pressed, the entered string gets sent to a Visual FoxPro Procedure that looks for any word within the blacklist in the entered string.  If it is found and error is word is saved within a return string and the *'s replace the bad word in the original string.  Both strings are then sent back to the web page (in real-time) and the return string displays an alert box explaining: "The following profanity will not be tolerated: [bad word]" and the original string is replaced with the bad word replaced with *'s.  (I know this explanation is convoluted but it works on my end....and thats all that matters).

Comment: Keep in mind that JS solutions can easily be circumvented. You need to filter the text again server-side after it has been submitted.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a potential solution, though I don't think it's free:
http://www.webpurify.com/profanity/filter/codesample.jquery.php